# What would the target matrix to train Neural Network?

Tags: matlab, classification, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm new at Artificial Neural Network and I'm using MATLAB developing Facial expression recognition and There are six expressions ; I'm not able to understand about **How to create a target matrix?** My Question is if I have SampleMatrix containing samples rows*columns. While rows are the features and 29 columns represents a single sample I meant to say **29 columns belongs to the same class** and If SampleMatrix dimensions are 21007*174. 174 columns because I have 6 classes 6*29=179 **What would the target matrix?**

Kindly Help me out!
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What sort of application are you working with? How does 29 becomes 174? What are the features? What are the classes?

Comment: working on facial expression recognition system I have computed Eigenfaces of sample images, classes are the 6 expressions. 29 columns for single expression So for 6 expressions; 6 multiply by 29 =174

Answer (score 2):

Example with the following numbers (I use random numbers):

- There are 6 possible classes (face expressions in your case).
- You have 2000 examples (lets say 2000 photos of faces from which you know the correct face expression).
- There are 30 features. From each example you have extracted the 30 features and know the correct class.

With these numbers, the **input matrix** would be a matrix of $30 \times 2000$, where each column $j$ is an example, and it has the 30 features of it. Hence, the position $(i,j)$ contains the feature $i$ of the example $j$.

The **target matrix** would be a matrix of $6\times 2000$. Where each column $j$ represents the correct class of the example $j$. The column is formed by zeros, and it has a $1$ at the row that indicates the class. If we have 6 classes, and the first example corresponds to class 3, the first column of the target matrix will be $[0 \ 0 \ 1\  0\  0\  0]$. If the second example corresponds to class 5, the second column of the target matrix will be: $[0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1\  0]$, and so on.

More info [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/classify-patterns-with-a-neural-network.html).